# Configuring Blackberry 10 SDK in Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, blackberry-10

I have been working on Blackberry 10 Cascades Native SDK. I tried to configure the SDK in Titanium Studio. Though the Titanium Dashboard indicates a green checker and states the SDK installed and configured, when i try to create a new project, the Blackberry SDK check option is still disabled. (Titanium is updated to the latest revisions. Blackberry 10 Native works fine. Simulator is good). Could somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

From [Appcelerator site](http://www.appcelerator.com/blackberry10/) :

> To get started developing your app, you can gain access to the public
>   [Titanium Mobile BlackBerry GitHub Repository](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile_blackberry). Installing the
>   BlackBerry 10 development tools are straightforward, and instruction
>   can be found at [README](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile_blackberry/blob/master/README.md). Read the [Terms and Conditions](http://www.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/bb10_promotion_terms.pdf) for this offer.

Hope this help you..

Comment: Hi Anand, thanks for the update. However, I have configured Blackberry 10 and also started developing on it. Titanium studio i have been using for about a year and also delivered an App to my client. Re-iterating my question- "The Blackberry 10 SDK shows configured on Dashboard, But is not enabled in The New Project second dialog, where we enter App Name and select Target SDKs. "

Comment: @user2426615: Thanks for your comment. If you got the correct answer and could develop for BB10, Please add it as a solution, so that it'll help others.